# How to make javadoc documentation available in JShell?

Tags: java, java-9, jshell

I am using JShell to test a library for which I made classes, sources, and javadoc available through the class path like so:

```
jshell --class-path library-javadoc.jar:library-sources.jar:library-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Still, when double tab after a documented Java identifier I receive:

```
<no documentation found>
```

How does JShell expect the documentation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems to be a unresolved issue: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8186876

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am using the Oracle JDK and not the open JDK. Is it likely that they share this issue?

Comment: It is the same code, Oracle develops the new code in OpenJDK