# Java 10: "No documentation found" for System.out.println(...)

Tags: debian, java-10, jshell, debian-buster

On a debian 10, I install Java SE 10 using `apt-get install openjdk-10-jdk openjdk-10-doc`. I called `jshell` and wanted to get the documentation of `System.out.println(...)`, but got an error `<no documentation found>`:

```
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 10.0.1
|  For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell> System.out.println( **<tab>**
Signatures:
void PrintStream.println()
void PrintStream.println(boolean x)
void PrintStream.println(char x)
void PrintStream.println(int x)
void PrintStream.println(long x)
void PrintStream.println(float x)
void PrintStream.println(double x)
void PrintStream.println(char[] x)
void PrintStream.println(String x)
void PrintStream.println(Object x)

<press tab again to see documentation>

jshell> System.out.println( **<tab>**
void PrintStream.println()
<no documentation found>

<press tab to see next documentation>

jshell> /env

jshell> System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"))
.

jshell>
```

I do not think this is related to [How to make javadoc documentation available in JShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47245854/how-to-make-javadoc-documentation-available-in-jshell) as I want to get the documentation for some standard method. (This question ends in bug https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8188142. Problem was that the classpath wasn't defined properly).

How do I get documentation in `jshell`?

Comment: I can confirm the tabs work fine with MacOSX and same java version. You sure about the `**tab**` sequence?

Comment: Yes I am sure about the tab sequence. Can you confirm the output of `/env` and `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Debian based system you will have to install the `openjdk-<vserion>-source` package to has JShell's documentation work. In your case you will need to execute

```sh
sudo apt install openjdk-10-source
```

The documentation you can get by double tab in JShell is from the `/usr/lib/jvm/java-<version>-openjdk-amd64/lib/source.zip` file which is a dead link before you install the `openjdk-<vserion>-source` package. The link is pointing at `../../openjdk-<vserion>/src.zip`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you require java 10? If not try downloading *java 8* using the command 
`sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre` to install *java-8* if that does not work we can talk through some steps to install *java 10*